# Playing from OGG stream using React Native

Tags: react-native, avplayer, audio-streaming, ogg

I'm looking for a way to play .ogg audio stream from url. I've tried using `react-native-sound-player` but it's using AvPlayer under the hood so it doesn't support ogg format.

Is there a way to play this audio format on React Native without having to write native ios/android implementations?

Comment: I'm afraid that this is currently not supported by any react-native library. There is a [Github issue](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/issues/590) for react-native-sound that has not yet been resolved for a very long time.